# Why are people who collect cardboard called '폐지 줍는 노인'?

Tags: vocabulary

I learned that the term for a 'refuse picker' or person who looks for recyclables is '폐지 줍는 노인' or '폐지 줍는 사람'. But when I look for translations of that term, '폐지' seems to mean *abolition*, and '폐지 줍는 사람' is an 'abolitionist'.

Why does '폐지 줍는 노인' refer to this occupation?

Comment: Wow, Google literally translates "폐지 줍는 사람" as "abolitionist".  So it understands 폐지 can be "abolition", 사람 can be "-ist", but decides to ignore "줍는".  Impressive in its own way!

Comment: @jick it made up its own pun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually old people(노인) looks for recyclables. So Koreans say like 폐지줍는 노인.

Comment: The word I didn't understand is 폐지 - google was translating it as 廢止('abolition'). But now I've searched again I see there's another homophonic word, 廢紙 (waste paper). Sorry, it's a trivial question after all!